# How to extract data and file name from args for upload files?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, asp.net-core-2.0, dropzone.js

I use dropzone.js with angular 6.x, TypeScript and ASP.net Core as the backend. I able to get all files from the dropzone.js module but I can't find how I can send them to the backend.

Let me show you some codes. I want to send a collection of files to the backend.
To do so, I have a media component with a global variable in which I add the file on each uploadsucess:

```
export class MediaComponent implements OnInit {
     public files: Array<FileParameter> = new Array<FileParam>();

     constructor(...){ ... }

     public onUploadSuccess(args): void {
        // Add the file to the collection
        this.files.push(args);
     }

     public onDropZoneQueueComplete($event, dz) {
        this._mediaService.post(this.files).subscribe(
            res => console.log(res),
            err => console.log("error on upload"),
            () => console.log("file uploaded"));
     }
}
```

Here is the service layer of _mediaService.post. This code has been generated by NSwagStudio. I guess I can only show you this part. I pretty sure it's enought to help me.

```
post(model?: FileParameter[] | null | undefined): Observable<FileResponse | null> {
    let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/Media";
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

    const content_ = new FormData();
    if (model !== null && model !== undefined)
      model.forEach(item_ => {
        content_.append("model", item_.data, item_.fileName ? item_.fileName : "model");
      });
}
```

So !! The problem is **model** and data from **args** DO NOT FIT!

Args is an array object with three indexes.
[image]
[image]

The model is of type of **FileParameter** this is the file that NSwag has genereted for **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile**

```
export interface FileParameter {
  data: any;
  fileName: string;
}

export class FileParam implements FileParameter {
  data: any;
  fileName: string;
}

export interface FileResponse {
  data: Blob;
  status: number;
  fileName?: string;
  headers?: { [name: string]: any };
}
```

Finally, I also tried this to fetch what I guess I have to from args but I got this error message **(TypeError: Object doesn't support this action any array javascript)**:

```
public onUploadSuccess(args): void {
    var file: FileParameter = new FileParam();

    for (var i = 0; i < args[1].files.length; i++) {
      file.data = args[1].files[i];
      this.files.push(file);

    }
  }
```

The action controller is for now simply like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IEnumerable<IFormFile> model)
        {
            return Content("Uploaded all media assets.");
        }
```

I try to see the uploaded files from model. It's always null.
Tell me how I can do this please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone struggle like I did, here the answer to the question:

First thing: NSwag generator will only create an interface for the type of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile. There is no class and no need too.

2: Change `public files: Array<FileParameter> = new Array<FileParam>();` to `public files: Array<any> = new Array<any>();`

3. Change onUploadSuccess(args) to onUploadSuccess($event)
4. Then change `this.files.push(args);` to `this.files.push({ data: $event[0], fileName: $event[0].name });` the $event at index 0 is important because this is the data that will correspond to the IFormFile.
5. Send all files to your service layer generated by NSwag. It will works nicely. Don't forget to clear **this.files** on completion as shown in the code below.

```js
public onDropZoneQueueComplete() {
    this._mediaService.post(this.files).subscribe(
        res => console.log(res.status),
        err => console.log("error on upload"),
        () => {
            console.log("file uploaded, files array is now reset.");
            this.files = new Array<any>(); /* Clear files! */
        });
}
```